Is there a way to set separate line colors to StyleClassedTextArea (RichTextFX) while appending a text
Trying to figure out is there any way to apply different line colors to StyleClassedTextArea . Appending some texts to text area this way
text_area_output_alpha.append(text.substring(startPosition, endPosition), "old-line-highlight");
and old-line-hightlight css will be
.old-line-highlight{
    -rtfx-background-color: #e13d3d;
}

this works fine but this style applies only to text and not getting applied to "\n" or blank lines.
I tried checking these .setStyle method,  -fx-fill:red and couple other combinations but no luck.
so is there a way to apply different line color while appending? can anyone help
